# shell expansion when special character [] and * in the expression

Tags: bash, shell

i have a question about the shell expansion when [] occur in the expression If i create a folder named test[12],then under this folder i have two files test1 test2 so when i using

```
echo test\[12\]/*
```

the output is

```
test[12]/test1 test[12]/test2
```

but when i use

```
echo test[12]/*
```

the output is

```
test[12]/*
```

what's the trick here, i know the [] is a pair of special characters, but i can not tell why the file expansion is depends on the []!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. No filename generation or path expansion should occur with *either* `echo` command; the first should print the literal string `test\[12\]/*`. The output you show is expected, though, for `echo test\[12\]/*` (no quotes).

Comment: sorry should not use the double quotes in the command, already updated the question

Answer (score 2):

When using `echo test\[12\]/*`, it will literally match like `test[12]/files`.

When using `echo test[12]/*`, it will match like `test1/files`, `test2/file`.

When using `[]` bash treated as a character class so the expansion is made and worked as special meaning.

Test it with by creating directory test1,test2 with file inside.

It will given the matched result.

Try to use `echo test[12]/*` instead of `echo "test[12]/*`.

When using `echo "test[12]/*"` it will literally print the content directly.

Comment: i think brace expansion {}is what you are talking about. but what i mean is [], BTW sorry for the double quotes, the original test should not include the double quotes!